# Kadma and Zakef Katan on one word

Tags: trop-cantillation

When reading Torah, many people (myself included) use a distinct tune when a kadma and a zakef katan appear on the same word (or two words joined with a makaf); e.g. from  [Sh'mot 34:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0234.htm):

> אֶ֨ת־הַדְּבָרִ֔ים

Yet I have not been able to find discussion of this anywhere. What is the name for this set of notes read in this way?

Comment: I have always said this as pashta zakef gadol although I have never heard a name for this combination

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rohav-lashon/5JV4h3A_CCg/D22t1VgGLTUJ

Comment: "Mesorah" (15c)

Comment: Think of it like the vertical part of a Zakef Gadol being separated off to the side.

Answer (score 2):

The first sign is called a מתיגה (and the second a זקף קטן as usual).

Comment: I have seen it also called a maqel.